# How to rename a file in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to rename the file if existing, the file will be moved successfully but the new file name will be like 0. the file will be shown only if I add .png manually to the name. I am not able to let the php rename the file correctly.

I have tried many suggested ways   here on stack overflow but the file won't be moved either will be renamed as 0.  a

It will be appreciated to let me know what is wrong with my code, please don't reply that I have to make my research first then write here, as I did already but I had no luck to figure it out myself.

**PHP**

```
$i = 0;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;

while(file_exists('../cutomeruploads/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
$actual_name = (string)$original_name;
$actual_name = $actual_name.(string)$i;
$name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
$i++;
}


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../cutomeruploads/'.$name)){
    $picname = $_FILES['upl']['name'];

    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have u tried the rename function of the php?

```
rename("The existing file name", "the new name");
```

Comment: Hi  I used the rename function and made some modifications, the code is renaming, I have answered my question bellow, I will be appreciated if you vote up my question too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a file in php is quite easy.

```
rename("oldfile.ext","newname.ext");
```

For more info see this: https://www.php.net/rename

Comment: Hi I used the rename function and made some modifications, the code is renaming, I have answered my question bellow, I will be appreciated if you vote up my question too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
/*
 * $dir - Directory path to check where the file is exist 
 * $filename - contains only name of the file
 * 
 */
public static function getFileName($dir, $filename) {

    // If name contains any white space replace with '-'
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $filename);

    $filePath = $dir . $filename;

    $fileInfo = pathinfo($filePath);
    $i = 0;
    $flag = false;

    while(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $filePath = $dir . $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . $i . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
        $i++;
        $flag = true;
    }
    if($flag === TRUE)
        return $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . $i . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
    else
        return $fileInfo['filename'] . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];

}
```

This is will return new `filename` if already exist one.

For example, `image.jpg` already exist, it automatically adding `image_1.jpg` , `image_2.jpg` and so on.

Comment: you have a syntax error on public static function getFileName($dir, $filename) {

Answer (score 0):

These changes renaming the file to xx1.ext xx2.ext

note:xx =     $orDi

```
$actual_name = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
while(file_exists('../cutomeruploads/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{ 
 $i++;          
$actual_name = (string)$orDi.(string)$i;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../cutomeruploads/'.$actual_name.".".$extension)){
    $picname = $actual_name.".".$extension;
```